# Using trigger with property from parent

Tags: wpf, triggers, grid, ismouseover

I have a Grid with a ToggleButton. The ToggleButton has a ControlTemplate and in this ControlTemplate I've defined a Ellipse and a Path. Atm the color on the Ellipse and the Path is changeing if the ToggleButtons IsMouseOver property is true. Now I want to change the color if the Grids IsMouseOver property is true as well. But I can't get it working.

My code looks like

```
                <Grid Height="26"
    x:Name="GroupboxHeader"
    Background="Blue">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Margin="0 0 5 0"
                OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
                Background="LightGray"
                Height="19"
                Width="19">
        <ToggleButton.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <TransformGroup.Children>
                                <TransformCollection>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                                </TransformCollection>
                            </TransformGroup.Children>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="circle"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Height="19"
                            Stroke="White"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Width="19" />
                    <Path x:Name="arrow"
                        Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="false"
                        Stroke="White"
                        StrokeThickness="2"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                            Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke"
                                TargetName="circle"
                                Value="LightGray" />
                        <Setter Property="Stroke"
                                TargetName="arrow"
                                Value="LightGray" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=GroupboxHeader, Path=IsMouseOver}">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke"
                                TargetName="circle"
                                Value="LightGray" />
                        <Setter Property="Stroke"
                                TargetName="arrow"
                                Value="LightGray" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ToggleButton.Template>
    </ToggleButton>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your ellipse/path stroke to `{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}`, and instead of using `TargetName` in your triggers change `BorderBrush` on your button. This way you can add triggers on grid with `TargetName` set to your toggle button to achieve desired behavior.

**EDIT:**

As this is not in control template, `TargetName` would not find child elements. Instead, you  can set triggers to:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}}" Value="True">
```

inside your `ToggleButton` style.

Comment: I've changed both Trigger like you said. The IsMouseOver for the ToggleButton is working but the IsMouseOver for the Grid isn't working. Same behaviour like before :/

Comment: Your second approach is working very well! Thank you